# How execute AND query in elasticsearch and aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have product_supplier Index which contains products and its suppliers. I have given suppliers names and I want to get the products which are supplied by the given suppliers.
For eg. I have given supplier "supplier1" and "supplier2". And I want to get "chips" and "mango" product as it's been supplied by this suppliers. And after that I want to aggregate the product name. Here is the total hits I have.

```
"hits":[
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "maggie",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "maggie",
          "product_supplier": "supplier2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "potatoes",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "chips",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "maggie",
          "product_supplier": "supplier3"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "mango",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "chips",
          "product_supplier": "supplier2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "8",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "chips",
          "product_supplier": "supplier3"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have query like this

```
GET /products_supplier/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "should": [
       {"term": {
         "product_supplier": {
           "value": "supplier2"
         }
       }},
       {"term": {
         "product_supplier": {
           "value": "supplier1"
         }
       }}
     ]
   }
 }, "aggs": {
   "product_name": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "product_name.keyword"
    }
   }
 }
}
```

And I'm getting this

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 6,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.3862944,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.3862944,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "maggie",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 1.3862944,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "chips",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.7985077,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "maggie",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.7985077,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "potatoes",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.7985077,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "chips",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "products_supplier",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 0.7985077,
        "_source" : {
          "product_name" : "mango",
          "product_supplier" : "supplier1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "product_name" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "chips",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "maggie",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "mango",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "potatoes",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i only like to get "mango" and "chips" product names

Answer (score 0):

You just got to break down the requirements one by one. Below is basic representation of the query in AND/OR form:

**(supplier1 OR supplier2) AND (mangoes OR chips)**

The below query is just ES Query representation of the above. Just replace `OR` with `should` clause while `AND` with `must` clause and you should be able to get the result you are looking for:

### Query Request

```
POST products_supplier/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_name.keyword": {
                      "value": "mango"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_name.keyword": {
                      "value": "chips"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_supplier.keyword": {
                      "value": "supplier1"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "product_supplier.keyword": {
                      "value": "supplier2"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "product_name":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"product_name.keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that in the above query, you are looking for exact matches, in that case I would recommend you to make use of `keyword` sibling of that field.

Also I've mentioned `minimum_should_match: 1` which means that the corresponding document would only return if any one of the values in the enclosing should clause matches.

### Query Response:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.4508328,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.4508328,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "chips",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1.4508328,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "mango",
          "product_supplier": "supplier1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products_supplier",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7",
        "_score": 1.3862944,
        "_source": {
          "product_name": "chips",
          "product_supplier": "supplier2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "product_name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "chips",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "mango",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Was the above answer useful? Please let me know if you have any queries